# reading from stdin in nodejs forcibly converts \r\n to \n

Tags: node.js, stream, newline, stdin

In a script i am trying to make, nodejs reads from stdin, but forcefully converts all \r\n to \n. This causes another of my script to produce improper results.

Is there a way i can prevent that from happening?

This is the code I am using to read from stdin.

```
process.stdin.resume();

process.stdin.setEncoding('ascii');

process.stdin.on('data', function(chunk){
    data += chunk;
})

process.stdin.on('end', function(){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this :

```
process.stdin.on('data', function(chunk){
      data += chunk.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n");
});
```

Comment: yes, but that is an extra step, i was thinking if i could prevent node from removing them by itself.